# How to generate client stubs from wsdl over https?

Tags: web-services, https, wsdl, client

I am a begginer in web-service world. For my current project i've to use a webservice over HTTPS replacing old HTTP service . What are the commands for generating the client stubs ? What extra parameter are needed for https compare to http ?

Comment: What are you using to generate the stubs?

Comment: hello i am using wsimport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup the keystore and truststore (which contains the server cert). You can usually do that either programmatically or via command line params to the Java VM. In your case, since you are running a third party tool, your only option is to pass in the command line params. Check [this post](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/using-jax-ws-based-web-services-wit.html) for an example.